# How to render a video with no proxy?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I wanted to add text to this 120 second video. I rebuilt the proxy and made it 25% so that it would be easier on my computer. When I was done adding my text I went to the view section on the top right corner and turned the proxy back to "no proxy; render all(something like that)" I previewed the video to make sure that none of the texts were off screen(too big).

I went to render it and as soon as the first text appeared I canceled because the proxy was still at 25%
So I thought I should go to the strips and un-check the proxy section and un-highlight the percentage of the proxy.
Tried again... didn't work.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

Go into the properties panel

Under the resolution (defaults to your screen resolution) you should see a percentage bar that ranges from 1% to 100%.

I think when you change the proxy settings blender automatically change that percentage to whatever proxy you chose.

Drag the bar back to 100%. make sure that your view properties are on without the proxy, full render and check your strips to make sure proxy/timecode is unchecked.

Configure your settings and you are ready to go!